# How to solve websocket ping timeout?

Tags: python, ssl, wamp, twisted, autobahn

While running the following piece of code (in theory it should send a value every minute)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions
options = CertificateOptions()
from os import environ
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner
from autobahn import wamp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import xlwings as wb
import time
import xlwings as wb

class Component(ApplicationSession):

"""
An application component that publishes an event every second.
"""

@inlineCallbacks
def onJoin(self, details):
    print("session attached")


while True:
    try:
        wb.Book(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Datasets\test_feed.xlsx')
        e = wb.Range('A2').value
        b = wb.Range('C2').value
        c = wb.Range('E2').value
    except Exception:
        print("----Waiting for RTD server response----")
        time.sleep(1)          
    try:                
        epoch = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
        result = epoch + timedelta(days=c)
        result = result.replace(microsecond=0, second=0)
        if result > now:
            now = result
            print("Stock", e, "Time", now, "Price", b)
            self.publish(u'com.myapp.ma', b)
    except Exception:
        print("-----Waiting1 for RTD server response----")
        time.sleep(1)
def onDisconnect(self):
        print("disconnected")
        reactor.stop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = ApplicationRunner(
        environ.get("AUTOBAHN_DEMO_ROUTER", u"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws"),
        u"crossbardemo")
    runner.run(Component)
```

The following error is returned

```
2017-12-28T18:43:52+0100 [Router       1604] dropping connection to peer tcp4:127.0.0.1:61531 with abort=True: WebSocket ping timeout (peer did not respond with pong in time)
2017-12-28T18:43:52+0100 [Router       1604] session "8526139172223346" left realm "crossbardemo"
```

What I've tried to solve this problem:

I)

> ```
> from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions
> options = CertificateOptions()
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     runner = ApplicationRunner(
>         environ.get("AUTOBAHN_DEMO_ROUTER", u"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws"),
>         u"crossbardemo", ssl=options)
>     runner.run(Component)
> ```

II)

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     runner = ApplicationRunner(
>         environ.get("AUTOBAHN_DEMO_ROUTER", u"ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws"),
>         u"crossbardemo",
>     )
>     runner.run(Component, auto_reconnect=True)
> ```

III)

> Regedit
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
> ```
>
> 1.0]
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
> ```
>
> 1.0\Client]
>       "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
>       "Enabled"=dword:00000001

IV)

> install certifi module (pip install certifi) set SSL_CERT_FILE, like
>   export SSL_CERT_FILE="$(python -m certifi)"

With still the same error. I am running on Windows 10, with crossbar demo router, autobahn and twisted.

Link to router configuration:

> https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/pubsub/basic/.crossbar

Also, the following example code is working properly:

```
counter = 100
        while True:
            print("publish: com.myapp.ma", counter)
            self.publish(u'com.myapp.ma', counter)
            counter += 100
            yield sleep(30)
```

Comment: You do not have a route to the server or the server isn't running.  First get ping to work from cmd.exe >Pin IP.  Don't use 127.0.0.1 (loopback) because most computers aren't configured to use loopback.  You would have to modify the host file on your PC for loopback to work.  Instead use the IP address of your computer.

Comment: @jdweng Tried your solution, unfortunately didn't work out. Got the next error:  failing WebSocket opening handshake ('Unsupported HTTP version ('HTTP/1.0')')

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Done.

Comment: Now you are actually connecting to a server while before you were not connecting.  Never seen error before HTTP/1.0.  There are two versions of HTTP 1) 1.0 : Stream 2) 1.1 Chunk.  Normally a webpage is backwards compatible so 1.1 works with 1.0, but a 1.0 will not always work with 1.1.  This is the first time I've seen a server not accept 1.0.  I don't see anything in the posted code that would force you client into 1.0.   The http header in you request is not compatible with server.  Normally I recommend using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help isolate issue.

Answer (score 2):

For Twisted to process further I/O events, you have to give control back to the reactor.  Twisted implements a cooperative multitasking system.  Various tasks run in the reactor thread.  This is accomplished by each task only spending a brief time in control.  Code like:

```
while True:
     ...
     sleep(1)
```

prevents any other tasks from gaining control to execute and also prevents the reactor from gaining control to service I/O events.

Since this code is within a function decorated with `inlineCallbacks`, there is a very small change that will make it at least not completely incompatible with Twisted's mode of operation.

Instead of `time.sleep(1)`, try this expression:

```
yield deferLater(reactor, 1, lambda: None)
```

And import `deferLater` from `twisted.internet.task`.  This will perform a "sleep" which gives control back to the reactor and lets other tasks execute during the sleep.  This should allow Autobahn to send the necessary ping/pong messages as well as allow it to process your `publish` call.

Comment: When changing to yield deferLater(reactor, 1, lambda: None), it gives the same error. When changing to (5), it gives the following error: session closed with reason wamp.close.transport_lost [WAMP transport was lost without closing the session before]. Is it safe to say that through Twisted, Autobahn or Crossbar sending data on a 'high' frequency is nearly infeasible?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't be the right conclusion to draw.

Comment: My guess is there's more blocking code somewhere in your application that's still interfering.

Comment: I've located the problem; it's xlwings that kills the connection. I thank you for your time.